# Is O(m+n) or O(mlgn) better

Tags: time-complexity

I was thinking whether O(m+n) or O(mlgn) is indeed better. If n is very large, I think the later is better? And in reverse, if m is very large, the first one wins? Am I right thinking like this?

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the fact that O(m+n) is not always better than  0(mlgn) but in general O(m+n) is more desirable. Check the following link about converting an O(mlgn) into O(m+n)

[Link](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/20064/my-concise-o-m-n-java-solution)

Comment: Whilst the link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.